# Form a magic square with assorted numbers

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers, magic-square

Arrange the following numbers in a way such that all rows, columns and the diagonals add up to the same number.

```
6   5   4   3
13  12  11  10
20  19  18  17
27  26  25  24
```

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Is this a puzzle you found elsewhere? If so, please [edit] the source into your question. We have an attribution policy here.

Comment: Do you really mean "product", which usually means multiplication between numbers? Or do you just want to construct a 4x4 magic square?

Comment: Apologies, a magic square.

Comment: While it's not too hard to construct a magic square with these numbers, I don't think it's a textbook problem, and I can't locate any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

> One can easily make a size 4 normal magic square by adding one with 4 times 1,2,3,4 and one with 4 times 0,4,8,12:
>  1: Put the numbers on the diagonal in any order. 2: Put the top row element on the other diagonal; but use the opposite available position for the two squares. 3: Fill in both squares, avoiding same numbers in all rows/columns 4: Add them up.
>
>  The requested numbers form 4 blocks of 4 , and replacing 0,4,8,12 with 2,9,16,23 (thus) leads to $24*24*2$ valid solutions this way, e.g. the blue one in the picture.
>  [image]

Comment: So basically you're finding two [mutually orthogonal latin squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares) but including the diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the answers:
> Let 3=<sub>0</sub>, 4=<sub>1</sub>, 10=<sub>0</sub>...
> So for the numbers we can get
> 0231
> 1320
> 2013
> 3102
> And adding the , , , 's (using some sudoku tricks) we have
> <sub>0</sub> <sub>2</sub> <sub>3</sub> <sub>1</sub>
> <sub>1</sub> <sub>3</sub> <sub>2</sub> <sub>0</sub>
> <sub>2</sub> <sub>0</sub> <sub>1</sub> <sub>3</sub>
> <sub>3</sub> <sub>1</sub> <sub>0</sub> <sub>2</sub>
> Or
> 3 26 13 18
> 11 20 5 24
> 19 10 25 6
> 27 4 17 12

Answer (score 0):

There are already two good answers. Here's the laziest approach, which only works because we are feeling lucky.

Step 1: Take any 4x4 magic square with the property that the numbers 1-4 don't appear in the same row, column, or diagonal, and the same is true for blocks 5-8, 9-12, and 13-16. The first completed grid in [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=4x4+magic+square&tbm=isch) will do nicely:

```
 8 11 14  1
13  2  7 12
 3 16  9  6
10  5  4 15
```

Step 2: add the block offsets 2, 5, 8, and 11 to blocks 1-4, 5-8, 9-12, and 13-16 respectively

> ```
>  13 19 25  3
>  24  4 12 20
>   5 27 17 11
>  18 10  6 26
> ```

This adds 2 + 5 + 8 + 11 = 26 to every row, column, and diagonal, so the result is still magic.

Step 3 (optional): [Permute](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/63317/36023) to taste.